# My form is inserting two records into my mysql table instead of one

Tags: php, forms, mysqli

I have a form that, onsubmit, inserts the data into a table in my database. It works fine except that it inserts two instances of data instead of one.  The first instance contains all the info from the form. The second instance contains blank info. My javascript validation is working fine.  Here is a trimmed down version of my code after connection :

```
// escape variables for security
$fname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['fname']);
$lname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['lname']);

$sql="INSERT INTO Persons (fname, lname) VALUES ('$fname', '$lname')";


if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}


mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

When I check my table in phpmyadmin, it contains 2 records, populated data and blank rows. Any thoughts?

Comment: You may want to breakdown your code into divided pieces and run them separately so see what is happening. For example, what happens when you run just that snippet that you have above? Because from the look of things it should work fine. If so, then your problem is with another part of your code.

Comment: Thank you for your advice on breaking the code down to the snippet. I just tried that, but with the same results in my table. first name ,last name was added but also a blank row.  Any further thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `<img src="" width="some number" height="some number">` to force a blank table cell in HTML causes a similar problem with Apache and MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

The variable $fname is declared twice, consequently overwriting itself. Thus the blank second instance.

Comment: Nice! Did not see that myself.

Comment: I am sorry but can you tell elaborate on the declared twice just a bit? which instance should I remove? Frome the mysqli_real_escape_string or the Values area? Thank you in advance!

Comment: @Robert Keith -under the comment //escape variables for security you define $fname twice.  should it be $fname and then $lname?

Comment: @SukieC  - I'm sorry but that was a typo while posting the question. in my coding, it actually is $lname which I will edit in my question now. Any thoughts on the corrected question?

Comment: i agree with @Mr. Concolato - the code snippet looks clean.  perhaps your code is being executed more than once?  For example, if your page submits to itself it might be inserting an empty row when first viewed and then a data record when submitted...

Comment: It's really strange.  My form, which is located on anypage.php, is submitting to insert.php.   <form action="insert.php" name="myform" method="post">.  I am really puzzled by this. Thank you for your valuable information. If you have any other ideas, please let me know. Otherwise, I will live with it for now.

Comment: could you post your table structure? Also, I've learned that using <img src="" width="some number" height="some number"> to force a blank table cell in HTML causes a similar problem with MySQL.

Comment: @SukieC After reading your post, I looked at my table structure and cleared all the img src I had. i uploaded and tested and now the problem is gone!  that is something I will have to remember in the future. Thank you for solving my issue!